# Command to generate string of lower case, upper case and numbers

Tags: perl, command-line

I have to modify this command to include random numbers and uppercase:

```
 perl -le "print map{('a'..'z')[rand 26]} 1..8"
```

I tried this so far:

```
perl -le "print map{('a'..'z')[rand 26]} map{(0..9)[rand 10]} 1..12"
```

It's only making it the string smaller and not generating any numbers in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Add upper case letters and numbers to your `map` list, and increase the number to 63 (52 letters plus 10 digits plus `!`):

```
perl -le "print map{('a'..'z','A'..'Z',0..9,'!')[rand 62]} 1..12"
```

Golfing is fun :)

```
perl -E"say map{(a..z,A..Z,0..9,'!')[rand 63]}a..l"
```